# How to write LINQ operation where by myself?

Tags: c#, string, linq, error-handling

I'm writing LINQ operations by myself. At the moment, I'm having trouble with *where*. Take a look at my code, this is `MyWhere` method:

```
public static T MyWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> myLst, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    T whereItem = default;
    foreach (var item in myLst)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(item))
        {
            whereItem = item;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return whereItem;
}
```

This is in main method:

```
var myWhereItem = fruits.MyWhere(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);

        Console.Write("MyWhere: ");
        foreach (string item in myWhereItem)
        {
            Console.Write(myWhereItem + ", ");
        }
```

How do I write Where method, currently it's LastOrDefault?

Comment: You return a `T` but expect an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: From the code of `MyWhere`, it seems like you're simply reproducing the functionality of `LastOrDefault` (e.g. `string myItem = fruists.LastOrDefault(f => f.Length < 6);`)

Comment: What should `MyWhere` do? What is your goal?

Comment: It should be like LINQ's Where method, my task is to write my own.

Comment: Then it should return IEnumerable<T> instead of T and it should [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) every element that matches the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyWhere` method returns a single value, not an enumeration of values. In your example code you call `MyWhere` which returns a single `string` value, which you then try to assign to an explicitly-typed `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you check the LINQ [definition for `From`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) you'll find that it actually returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. If you're trying to replicate the LINQ functionality (which is probably a Really Bad Idea) the simplest option (in modern C#) is to use an enumerable method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

(This is simply syntactic sugar (compiler-supported shorthand) to generate a complete `IEnumerable<T>` implementation in the background, making it easier to implement.)

If you're just trying to figure out how LINQ works, it's not hard to read [the actual source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs) for it.